# On proof of Sauer's lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics, machine-learning

Let $X$ be a (possibly infinite) set. We consider a subset $H$ of the set $\{0,1\}^X$ of functions $X\to\{0,1\}$. Given a finite subset $B\subset X$, we denote by $H_B$ the set of restrictions to $B$ of elements of $H$, that is, the image of $H$ by the restriction map $\{0,1\}^X\to\{0,1\}\to B$. If $H_B=\{0,1\}$ (or equivalently if $|H_B| = 2^{|B|}$), we say that $H$ *shatters* $B$.

(definition provided [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf) on page 69)

---

Consider $X,B,H$ as above. Fix an element $c_1\in B$. Given $h\in\{0,1\}^X$, define its "brother" $\hat{h}\in\{0,1\}^X$ as equal to $1-h(c_1)$ on $c_1$ and equal to $h$ elsewhere. Define $H'$ as the set of $h\in H$ such that there exists $g\in H$ such that $h$ and $\hat{g}$ coincide on $B$.

(definition is on page 75)

---

I am considering the proof of Sauer's lemma [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf) from page 74. It is proven by induction, and the proof consists mostly in saying that

$$|H_A|\le|\{B \subseteq A : H \text{ shatters }B \}| \ \ \ \ \  (1)$$

I want to add additional requirement, which leads to

$$|H_A| = |\{B \subseteq A : H \text{ shatters }B \}| \ \ \ \ \  (2)$$

all the time when this requirement is satisfied and when it is not satisfied, I want to prove that

$$|H_A| < |\{B \subseteq A : H \text{ shatters }B \}| \ \ \ \ \  (3)$$

Am I correct in the assumption that the only requirement for it to be true is $H' = H$ for all $H'$ defined on connected with them subsets $B$? If it is true, then is it correct to say, that strict equality '<' as in (3) is achieved if and only if there exist some element in A, which either classified as 0 or as 1 by **all** functions in H? And when for every element $x$ from $A$ there exist $h_1$, $h_2$ from $H$ so that $h_1(x) = 0$ and $h_2(x) = 1$, we have equality '=' as in (2)?

---

I am asking this as part of finding an answer to [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731456/excercise-on-sauers-lemma) question of mine.

Comment: You might define "shatter" you get more feedback.

Comment: @YCor I've added definition of "shatter".

Comment: Thanks. Possibly also introduce the question so readers can understand it without going into the link (I would start by the definitions, then ask the question, and then give motivation).

Comment: @YCor Thank you for a great suggestion. Restructured now.

Comment: I've edited to clarify the context. Still I don't understand what is the question. I can summarize what you write as "I want to add an additional requirement, which leads to (2), and which, when not satisfied, implies that (2) fails". Requirement in terms of what?

Comment: @YCor It is difficult to explain, but if you look under the EDIT https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731456/excercise-on-sauers-lemma, then you will find such "requirement" for right inequality. I want to find similar explanation for the left inequality.